# Factorization in the ring of integers of a particular biquadratic number field, and questions about norms

Tags: nt.number-theory, number-fields, elementary-proofs

Consider the number field $K={\mathbb Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ and its ring of integers ${\mathcal O}_K$. I have been doing some calculations with this number field as a toy example, to see what can be done with basic tools (e.g. at the level of Stewart and Tall's book on algebraic number theory).

After lots of messy hacking I found that this example, and many others, have properties listed in the L-functions and modular forms database: [here is the entry](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/4.4.2304.1). While most of it confirms what I had been doing, I hadn't managed to show that this field has class number one, and indeed I thought I had found an example of non-unique factorization into irreducibles.

Q1. How are the calculations of class groups done behnd the scenes, in e.g. Sage?

(That is, the webpage tells you which command to type in order to get the answer, but I wondered if this is done merely by a look-up table for fields of low degree or if there is some algorithm arising from the Minkowski bound.)

My second question is perhaps slightly inappropriate for MathOverflow since I am really asking for help finding my mistake. But perhaps there is some "research-level" content involved in explaining what is going on more generally for biquadratic number fields.

The example that made me think ${\mathcal O}_K$ is not a UFD is

$$(5+\sqrt{2})(5-\sqrt{2})=(3\sqrt{3}+2)(3\sqrt{3}-2)$$

(these are "normal" brackets, not notation for an ideal).

Now $5+\sqrt{2}$ is not an associate of $3\sqrt{3}\pm 2$ (for if $r_{\pm} =(5+\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{3}\pm2)^{-1}$, a direct calculation shows that ${\rm Tr}(r_{\pm})\notin {\mathbb Z})$. So if we did have unique factorization in this ring, either $5+\sqrt{2}$ or $3\sqrt{3}+2$ would fail to be irreducible. But both of these have norm $23^2$, so if either one is reducible there exists some $x\in {\mathcal O}_K$ with $N(x)=23$.

Q2. Could someone show me an $x\in {\mathcal O}_K$ which has norm 23 and divides either $5+\sqrt{2}$ or $3\sqrt{3}+2$? Or if no such $x$ exists, could someone show me where the error is in my previous paragraph?

The reason I thought no such $x$ exists is because another brute-force computation, once I had found an integral basis for ${\mathcal O}_K$, seemed to indicate that $N(x)$ is always congruent to a square number mod 3, for every $x\in {\mathcal O}_K$. In particular $N(x)\not\equiv 2 \bmod 3$.

Q3. In practice, is there a way to determine or restrict the possible residue classes mod $p$ of $\{ N(x) \colon x\in {\mathcal O}_K\}$, if $p$ is one of the ramified primes for the number field?

Comment: There are elements with negative norm, e.g., $3+\sqrt2+2\sqrt3+\sqrt6$. Perhaps there are elements with norm $-23$? [In fact, I think that element is one of them.]

Comment: Q1 is perhaps a bit too open-ended for this forum; you might want to refer to Henri Cohen's book "A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory".

Comment: Thanks both! I agree with @GerryMyerson's calculation - that was indeed an embarrassing oversight on my part. I haven't had the patience to test if that element or one of its conjugates divides $5+\sqrt{2}$ or $3\sqrt{3}+2$ but certainly Q2 is left looking a bit silly now. I will perhaps edit the question to reflect this when I get a free moment